# In WinRT, loading images in listbox by enabling VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode as Recyling, image get blurred

Tags: image, listbox, winrt-xaml

I have added items in listbox as 50 images by enabling VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode as Recyling. By scrolling the listbox, images in the listbox get blurred. Any one have idea on this to resolve the issue ?

Comment: Facing the issue by scrolling the listbox

Comment: Got solution through https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/89ec4570-1120-4b01-8b69-dfcc3bc40186/in-winrt-loading-images-in-listbox-by-enabling-virtualizingstackpanelvirtualizationmode-as?forum=winappswithcsharp